# Properly view Heimdall

Tags: flash, firmware, heimdall

In Ubuntu 14.04 when I download Heimdall frontend and open it, I get a view that is devoid of any options I must fill in such as flash tab, etc. What I get is a Archive Manager generic view with none of the necessary tabs. I guess this question must seem silly, but it has become so frustrating, especially when I am looking at a bootlooped S5. Thank you for any help.Heimdall

Comment: where did you get the heimdall-frontend from? did you unpack the archive and run the included script/binary? did you download and unpack the heimdall commandline tool package as well?
I figured you downloaded the stuff from https://bitbucket.org/benjamin_dobell/heimdall/downloads? - which one exactly?

Comment: Please just follow this guide: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_klte